# How does a jar pull transitive dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I am buliding small Spring Boot app -  pacakged as jar file (I'm using maven plugins).
I know that there are solutions which allow me to build jar file with all desired dependecies (e.g. maven assembly plugin).
The question is what if I don't pack maven required depedencies using those solutions? Am I correct that I will always get "NoClassDefFoundError" ? So should I always pack my project with all depedencies into jar file or there is another solution to "makes thigns work"?

Comment: There are multiple ways to make things work, but if you want an executable jar, this is the *best* way to make things work. You could also probably set up a class path and force the jar user to have the correct dependencies in the correct place.

Comment: In spring boot you should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin which handles the packaging in the correct way. Do not try to do via maven-assembly-plugin...